# How to log to Kubernetes Container Log from Python process

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

With Kubernetes Container running a Python script:

```
import time
while True:
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            if i==0:
                raise Exception('Exception occurred!')
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(1)
```

I would like to pass the Exception's message `'Exception occurred!'` down to the Container so this error message could be seen with:

`kubectl describe pod pod_id`

Would it be possible?

Comment: What you have right now will be visible in `kubectl logs ..`. if you want it in the output of `kubectl describe pod...`, you'll need to write it to create it as a kubernetes event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything you `print()` will be visible in `kubectl logs`.  (You may need to set an environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in your pod spec.)

Your code as you've written it will never print anything.  The construct

```py
try:
  ...
except:
  pass
```

silently ignores any and all exceptions out of the `try` block.  The bare `except:` even captures some system-level exceptions like `SystemExit` or `KeyboardInterrupt`; this is almost always wrong.  Often you want your `except` blocks to be as tightly scoped as you can, and the Python tutorial on [user-defined exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#tut-userexceptions) is a helpful pattern.

(The exception to this, particularly in a Kubernetes context, is that you will often want a very broad exception handler to do something like return an HTTP 500 error to a network request, rather than crashing the application.)

A better example might look like:

```py
import time

class OneException(Exception):
  pass

def iteration():
  for i in range(10):
    try:
      if i == 1:
        raise OneException("it is one")
      print(i, math.sqrt(i), math.sqrt(-i))
      # will work when i==0 but fail when i==2
    except OneException as e:
      print(i, repr(e))
      # and proceed to the next iteration

if __name__ == '__main__':
  while True:
    # The top-level loop.  We want a very broad catch here.
    try:
      iteration()
    except Exception as e:
      print('iteration failed', repr(e))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` did the trick for me, thank you!

Comment: If i want to use logging module not print(). Will that work with PYTHONUNBUFFERED= 1?